# Efficient data structure to keep dictionary-like observations keyed by time in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, data-structures, time-series

I have a list of observations tied to a datetime that could be represented either by a dict or by an object, something like this:

```
Datetime         | Data
--------------------------------------------------------
2018-01-20 20:00 | {'word1': 3, 'word2': 5, 'wordX': 1}
2018-01-20 20:01 | {'word1': 2, 'word2': 2, 'wordX': 5}
2018-01-20 20:05 | {'word3': 2, 'word6': 1, 'word1': 1}
```

The amount of observations can be in the order of millions. My main problem, as I see it, is that **the amount of keys in the `Data` object varies**.

I want to be able to aggregate the weighted words by various time intervals (for example, each 10 minutes, each 10 hours, etc.) by calculating the sum of weights assigned to specific words for those intervals.

I want to use Pandas for this but I'm at a loss of which data structure to choose since my date key is not evenly spaced and can be non-uniqie.

My first idea was to keep a separate dict of the dictionary objects, keyed by a UUID, and have a Pandas timeseries hold the mapping of the datetime to those UUIDs. That way, I could get the per-interval buckets of UUIDs and then manually iterate over them with my custom aggregation. Is this as bad an idea as it sounds? I'd really appreciate a kick in the right direction.

Comment: Groupby by using a Grouper should work well for you. Can you give me specific example of what you would like?

Comment: Unfortunately, pandas is going to be useless as long as you're working with columns of objects (and not numeric/string/datetimes). You may as well write a loop and do it faster.

Comment: @GabrielA Now that I typed out the question, I'm not even sure if keeping an unstructured object in any Pandas data structure is even possible -- in my case the amount of keys in `Data` will vary. Is something like Panel worth looking at or am I headed in the wrong direction here?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I was hoping to at least utilize the resampling in Pandas (or some sort of a Groupby as GabrielA mentions) -- is that something worth looking into? (and thanks for answers folks, I'm out of my comfort zone here and really appreciate any perspective)

Comment: Well, are all your dictionaries word : count mappings?

Comment: Also, assuming you're resampling every 10 minutes, what is your expected output for this data sample? That should give me a good idea.

Comment: Yes. I can also live with something like (['word1', 'word2'], 4) -- i.e. an observation that contains a list of words and a weight (so no weight specific to a single word).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I essentially want to chart how much the tokens/words were mentioned, over various time intervals, and identify the popular/unusual ones. The number associated with a observation is the weight/popularity of that observation (can be a single tweet/social post for example, in that case the author's followers count would be the weight value)

Comment: So, is the output like this: `{'word1': 6, 'word2': 7, 'wordX': 6, ...}`?

Comment: For a single time interval -- yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your `Datetime` column to `datetime`, if it isn't already:

```
df.Datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime)
```

Since you have a dictionary of counts, you can convert each one to a `Counter` object, because these support `__add__`ition and will work well with resample.

Set `Datetime` to the index, resample, and find the sum.

```
from collections import Counter
r = df.set_index('Datetime').Data.apply(Counter).resample('10min').sum()
```

```
print(r)

2018-01-20 20:00:00    {'word1': 6, 'word2': 7, 'wordX': 6, 'word3': ...
Freq: 10T, Name: Data, dtype: object
```

The given example resamples data every 10 minutes. This works only due to the nature of your data, having counts as the values. If it isn't, you'll need to write your own loop and get it done.

Comment: Thanks, this is great, I'll try this now but this is pretty much what I wanted so I count this solved. Somewhere in here, a good lesson for me about not treating everything like nails when you have a hammer.